# How to install a Visual Studio Code extension from GitHub?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for some guidance on how to install https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2 in Visual Studio Code.

I am on a Mac if it matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the market link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2. Alternatively you can search the name `CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2` inside VSCode's `EXTENSIONS: MARKETPLACE`

Comment: @Outman The one in Marketplace is v1.

I am looking to install v2.

"v2 Uses the same bracket parsing engine as VSCode, greatly increasing speed and accuracy. A new version was released because settings were cleaned up, breaking backwards compatibility."

Comment: There are 2 versions in the market by the same developer **CoenraadS**, one of which is `Bracket Pair Colorizer 2` and is currently version 0.0.25 (beta).